# How to use ImageJ in Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, imagej

I am developing an android application in which I am trying to replicate the mapir plugin of fiji. I have searched on internet and I came to know that ImageJ2 can be useful for this. How to use it in my android project? And is ImageJ2 and ImageLib2 different? Help is being deeply appreciated. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2) and its foundational layers [ImgLib2](http://imagej.net/ImgLib2) and [SciJava](http://imagej.net/SciJava) are designed in a way to avoid any dependencies on AWT or Swing, so they *should* be compatible with Android. This is being discussed on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/tags/android).

Citing @ctrueden from [there](http://forum.imagej.net/t/using-imagej-with-android/2517/2?u=imagejan):

> Unfortunately, no one is (yet) using ImgLib2 or ImageJ2 on Android in anger. So if you try it, expect numerous obstacles.

Comment: Does ImageJ2 provides same functionality as it have in its previous version? Basically my task is I need to convert this code:[link]https://github.com/mapircamera/Fiji/blob/master/plugins/Calibration/Calibrator.java into android. So, If it is providing same functionality then, should it be a easy task?

Comment: @JayTanna it won't be straight-forward though. You'll have to replace `ij.ImagePlus` by `net.imagej.ImgPlus` and get rid of all other `ij.*` dependencies in favor of their `net.imagej.*` counterparts. As mentioned, ask on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) for more help on this.

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083570/applying-color-gradient-on-an-image-in-android

Comment: can you help me with this question? link is in above comment