# Applying color gradient on an image in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, gradient, qgis

I am trying to replicate the functionalities of QGIS software in an Android application. I want to apply a color gradient (Red to Green lut) on an image for further efficient analysis.

[image: Color Gradient (Red to Green lut)]

The image shown below is generated after applying the NDVI (Normalised Difference Vegetation Index) indicator on it. The value of NDVI ranges from -1 to +1.

[image]

The image shown below is generated after applying the color gradient on it. This image now can be analysed efficiently because it shows the plants as green and the ground as red.

[image]

I tried the following code in Android for the result where NDVI is the NDVI value ranging from -1 to +1. I have not added the code for finding out the maximum and minimum value of NDVI but for my image, minimum value of NDVI is 0.11 and maximum value of NDVI is 0.57:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                final int pixel1 = src1[i][j];
                final int pixel2 = src2[i][j];

                final double X = pixel2 - pixel1;
                final double Y = pixel2 + pixel1;

                final double NDVI = (X / Y);

                R = (int) ((255 * NDVI) / maxNDVI);
                G = (int) (((255 * (maxNDVI - NDVI)) / maxNDVI));
                B = 0;

                pixels[i][j] = Color.argb((Color.alpha(pixel1)), R, G, B);
         }
}
```

But I am not getting the appropriate result. Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: thanks for the code of ColorMatrixColorfilter. But how did you get the lower image? The one wher eyou have used LinearGradient. Can you show how to use LinearGradient? @pskink

Comment: i am sorry for the late reply but once you posted those links, i got a better idea of how it is working. can you show me how to use LinearGradient? i see that you have applied that in the lower image but i don't knwo how. @pskink

Comment: I tried ColorMatrixColorFilter and it works properly. But the only issue is that we are not taking into consideration  the value of NDVI index. Which is why I am not getting different shades as shown in the picture (color gradient) above. There are regions where I should get yellow or light green but I am getting just one shade of red and green. @pskink